# url rewriting not working in php

Tags: url-rewriting

I have created a `.htaccess` file and added some rewrite rules to it, but it is not working as expected

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home?$ index.php
RewriteRule ^live/(.+)$  user_stream_view.php?id=$1
```

The first  rule is working fine. The second one is also rendering it is not giving any 404 error, instead all css and the content gets messed up

[image: Screenshot of webpage with dead images]

Comment: Haven't you forget `\r\n` in your code?

Comment: where? can you send me the whole rewrite rule? i am a newbie at this so cant really figure where to add \r\n

Comment: Where your `user_stream_view.php` is exactly located? I think, you should write correct `RewriteBase`

Comment: it is located at root

Comment: Why do you think `^live/(.+)$` complies url `/freefootball(sohail)/live/39`?
Read this: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: can you provide me the regex for /freefootball(sohail)/live/39 ? i still have a lot of working to do,i will read the article afterwards

Comment: No-no-no: SO is the community to help do your well, not to do your work instead of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with stylesheets has no matter with url-rewriting.
You should write urls to stylesheets in your template from slash like that:

```
/styles/main.css
```

Now I think, you use `styles/main.css`, and browser tries to load it from `/freefootball(sohail)/live/`.

Try this rewrite to check:

```
RewriteRule ^/freefootball(sohail)/live/(.+)$  user_stream_view.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks,The issue was actually of path it was changing after adding the regex of .htaccess, Thanks anyways